# Strange warning of front increment operator

Tags: c++

I have implemented an "incremental mean" (I am posing just the .cpp file)

```
#include "../hpp/CIncrementalMean.hpp"

IncrementalMean::IncrementalMean() : m_mean(0.0), m_cntr(0) {}

IncrementalMean::~IncrementalMean() {}

void IncrementalMean::addValueToMean(double valIn)
{
  m_mean = (m_cntr * m_mean + valIn) / ++m_cntr;
}

int IncrementalMean::getCounter() const
{
  return m_cntr;
}

double IncrementalMean::getMean() const
{
  return m_mean;
}
```

And when I build it (gcc4.9 Ubuntu14.04), I get the following warning:

```
warning: operation on ‘((IncrementalMean*)this)->IncrementalMean::m_cntr’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

I am not sure why it is displayed. Can someone give me an advise? Shall I do

```
m_mean = (m_cntr * m_mean + valIn) / (m_cntr + 1);
m_cntr++;
```

instead?

But anyway, can someone explain me the warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: You are lucky that you got warning. Now fix it as later code you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m_mean = (m_cntr * m_mean + valIn) / ++m_cntr;
        ^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^
         READING                     WRITING
```

You are reading and writing a variable without a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the operations. This can be rearranged by your compiler and thus it is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) :D

**EDIT**:
complementing a little bit, you'll have less floating point error accumulation if you use:

```
m_mean += (valIn - m_mean) / ++m_cntr;
```

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing)) **AND** you'll avoid the Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Then, I shall slit it in two lines: `m_mean = (m_cntr * m_mean + valIn); m_mean /= ++m_cntr;`

Answer (score 3):

Let us simplify your code to identify the problem:

```
a = 0;
b = a / ++a;
```

What division is performed exactly in line 2? You are probably thinking that it must be:

```
b = 0 / 1;
```

When in fact the compiler is free to evaluate `++a` first and `a` second, giving you:

```
b = 1 / 1;
```

So what does the code do? The technical term is "undefined behavior", but all you need to remember is "don't increment a variable and use it again in the same expression".

Regarding your design, it would probably make much more sense to have two data members `counter` and `sum` and defer the division to a member function called `calculateMean` or something. Then you don't have to multiply and divide (I smell precision problems!) every time `addValue` is called.

Comment: And If the values are big and many... it may overflows... How big is the difference (in cycles)?

Comment: Actually, incremental updating off the mean introduces **less** errors than calculating it all in the end.

Comment: @Massa Let's say we want to calculate the mean of three numbers a, b and c. Are you seriously saying that `(a + b + c) / 3` is going to be less precise than `(((((0 * 0 + a) / 1) * 1 + b) / 2) * 2 + c) / 3`?

Comment: @FredOverflow now let's say you want to calculate the mean of three billion numbers... Read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing) and you are going to understand...

Comment: @Massa The accepted answer has two formulas, one of them with precision problems, which is exactly the one OP has provided. Note in my example how each division by x is immediately cancelled out with a multiply by x; this obviously cannot be good for precision.

Comment: That's why I brought the other formula (`m_mean += (valIn - m_mean) / ++m_cntr`) to attention in my edit :D But you are absolutely right WRT "cannot be good for precision"...

Comment: @Massa Very nice. I hereby retract my objections ;)

Answer (score 2):

The GNU compiler collection (GCC) since 4.6.3 warns when the sequence order of operations is ambiguous.

Since you are modifying m_cntr in denominator and using this value in calculations in numerator, it is not obvious what will be done (i.e. which part of this fraction will be calculated earlier). So, it is better to avoid such constructions.